# Jquery sequential display units when the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a simple code :

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xmocartx/sr194nsb/4/

The problem is that when you hover the mouse fast blocks mixed.
In Jquery I am a newbie. Please tell me how to fix this? Thank you.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var flag = 1;
var liLength = $(".slideMenu ul li").length;
var num = 1;
var numHover;
var numTmp=0;
$(".slideMenuCont .item").fadeOut(0);
$(".slideMenuCont .item:eq(0)").fadeIn(500);            
var myInterval = function(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(num>=liLength)
            num=0;
        $(".slideMenu ul li").removeClass("active");
        $(".slideMenu ul li:eq("+num+")").addClass("active");
        $(".slideMenuCont .item").fadeOut(0);
        $(".slideMenuCont .item:eq("+num+")").fadeIn(500);
        num++;
    },3000);
}
var stop = function(){
    clearInterval(interval)
}
$(".slideMenu ul li").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        stop();
        if(num>=1)
            numTmp=num-1;
        else numTmp=num;
        numHover=$(".slideMenu ul li").index(this); 
        num=numHover;
        if(numHover!=numTmp){
            $(".slideMenu ul li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".slideMenuCont .item").fadeOut(500);
            $(".slideMenuCont .item:eq("+num+")").fadeIn(500);
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if(num<liLength)
            num++;
        myInterval();
    }
});
var Auto = function(){
    myInterval();
}
Auto();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a try.

This should fix the display Issue while preserving the 500 sec fade in.

It basically clears the display contents when moving the mouse fast so you dont get the messy transitions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var flag = 1;
var liLength = $(".slideMenu ul li").length;
var num = 1;
var numHover;
var numTmp=0;
$(".slideMenuCont .item").fadeOut(0);
$(".slideMenuCont .item:eq(0)").fadeIn(500);            
var myInterval = function(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(num>=liLength)
            num=0;
        $(".slideMenu ul li").removeClass("active");
        $(".slideMenu ul li:eq("+num+")").addClass("active");
        $(".slideMenuCont .item").fadeOut(500);
        $(".slideMenuCont .item:eq("+num+")").fadeIn(500);
        num++;
    },3000);
}
var stop = function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
$(".slideMenu ul li").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        stop();
        $(".slideMenu ul li").removeClass("active");
        if(num>=1)
            numTmp=num-1;
        else numTmp=num;
        numHover=$(".slideMenu ul li").index(this); 
        num=numHover;
        if(numHover!=numTmp){
            $(".slideMenuCont .item").fadeOut(0);
            $(".slideMenuCont .item").stop().fadeOut(500); 
            $(".slideMenuCont .item").css("display","none");
            $(this).addClass("active");
             $(".slideMenuCont .item:eq("+num+")").fadeIn(500);
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if(num<liLength)
            num++;
        myInterval();
    }
});
var Auto = function(){
    myInterval();
}
Auto();
```

});

Update: trying Combining both   $(".slideMenuCont .item").stop().fadeOut(500);  and
                               $(".slideMenuCont .item").css("display","none");

Comment: This is an option . But the slide changes occur suddenly . Effort on the eyes )

Comment: On another site , I was offered to add .stop().fadeOut(500);

Comment: That is an option also, but I still see blurring of content with .stop();fadeOut(500).  If you alter your menu items to have different words for each item its more noticeable.

Comment: trying combining both effects together:   $(".slideMenuCont.item").stop().fadeOut(500);  and
 $(".slideMenuCont .item").css("display","none");